# send tomcat conf files to container using kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, tomcat7, kubernetes, docker-container

I am new to docker and Kubernetes, I am trying to create a container having `tomcat7/Java7` so that I could deploy my `webapps` into it. The only concern I have are the `tomcat/conf` config files, which have details of `database connections`, `threadpool`, `Java Memory` etc.

What I want is to copy these files from Kubernetes server to docker-container and place them at right places, while starting the container.

P.S: I don't want to do it via enviroment variables, as they are going to be huge in numbers if I keep a variable for every entry in config files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a ConfigMap in your Kubernetes, from your tomcat config (files or a whole dir)

```
kubectl -n staging create configmap special-config --from-file={path-to-tomcat-conf}/server.xml
```

And then mount it on your pod (kubectl create -f path/to/the/pod.yaml)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: tomcat-test-pod
spec:
 containers:
 - name: test-container
   image: tomcat:7.0
   command: [ "catalina.sh", "run" ]
   volumeMounts:
   - name: config-volume
     mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
 volumes:
 - name: config-volume
   configMap:
    # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
    # to add to the container
    name: special-config
```

[Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-specific-path-in-the-volume)